# Library to do "feature highlighting" in web app

Tags: library, javascript, html, css

I am looking a library or some example code to do feature highlighting in my web app. What I mean by that: When you first open a web app, often there is a feature where different parts of the UI are highlighted one after the other with a description next to it. This way you get a quick introduction how the web app works. I found this feature in material disign for iOS: https://material.io/develop/ios/supporting/feature-highlights

[image]

But I am using angular material and I could not find the feature there. Does anyone know a library which helps me do this kind of thing? Or maybe some example code? Or maybe just the name of this design feature, if it has one, because I had hard time googling for it.

Thank you!